# What is PDN in these questions?

Tags: homework, vlsi

[image]

I don't know what PDN stands for.

Can you give me some hint to solve these problem. I'm appreciate.

Comment: I have no source, this is the problem in my VLSI lab that I received from my teacher.

Comment: @Southgoodman That *is* a source, and should be mentioned in the question. The fact that it's not online or not a published work doesn't make it not a source.

Comment: Sure sir, I drop the link to this Lab here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/12q93GHREmvWDlk2AoJO1TQgc3W3-UXWW/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2):

In logic circuitry contexts, PDN = pull-down network and PUN = pull-up network.